# Why is this program giving the result 0 or garbage value although all the conditions have been met?

Tags: c, if-statement

As I read it is okay to write the `if else` without the `else` clause.

Program to find the largest of three given numbers:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

int a, b, c, big;

printf("Enter three given numbers : ");

scanf("%d%d%d", &a, &b, &c);

// if (1>2) (1>3) (2>3)
 
 

if (a > b) //  1>2

{    

    if (a > c)

        big = a;

    else

        big = c;
}
  printf("The largest numnber is = %d",big);

return 0;

}
```

Comment: if `a>b` is false, what will be the value of `big`?

Comment: You aren't initializing `big`, so if `a > b` is false, you're printing an indeterminate value.

Comment: Would encourage you to learn to debug effectively so that you can find these issues out for yourself. Run your program in a debugger and trace its flow and variable values as it runs. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: don't forget the use cases where `a==b`, `a==c`, and `a==b==c`. I remember this exact same assignment way back when,,, lost some points because I didn't handle those use cases. Best IMO just to do `big = a;` (or `b` or `c`) unconditionally and check against the other two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it more clear this if statement

```
if (a > b) //  1>2

{    

    if (a > c)

        big = a;

    else

        big = c;
}
```

may be rewritten like

```
if (a > b) //  1>2
{    
   //.. unimportant
}
```

provided that `a` is not greater than `b`. That is in this case the sub-statement of the if statement that represents the compound statement will not get the control. And as a result the variable `big` will not be initialized.

Your program could look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, big;

    printf( "Enter three numbers: " );

    scanf( "%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c );

    if ( !( a < b ) && !( a < c ) )
    {
        big = a;
    }
    else if ( !( b < c ) )
    {
        big = b;
    }
    else
    {
        big = c;
    } 
 
    printf( "The largest number is = %d\n", big );

    return 0;
}
```

Pay attention to that the user can enter for example three numbers equal each other.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the branch where this is `false`:

```
if (a > b)
```

`big` will then be left uninitialized and have an indeterminable value.

To catch all combinations using only two comparisons, you could do like this:

```
    if (a > b) big = a;
    else       big = b;

    if(c > big) big = c;
```

A more general form:

```
   int arr[...] = {filled with values};
   big = arr[0];
   for(size_t i = 1; i < sizeof arr / sizeof *arr; ++i) {
       if(arr[i] > big) big = arr[i];
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

My two cents for the simplest solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int big, b, c; // only need 3 variables
    printf("Enter three given numbers : ");
    // should check this return value
    scanf_s("%d%d%d", &big, &b, &c);  // assume first value entered is largest

    if (b > big) big = b;  // b larger? reassign
    if (c > big) big = c;  // c larger? reassign

    // big is now the largest number entered
    printf("biggest number is %d\n", big);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Logically your programm is not correct. After `if` you should use `else`.

In your programm, when you input numbers {1,2,3}, `big` is never initialized. However if you input {3,2,1} it will output correct result.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a, b, c, big;
    printf("Enter three given numbers : ");
    scanf_s("%d%d%d", &a, &b, &c);
    if (a > b)
    {
        if (a > c)
            big = a;
        else
            big = c;
        printf("The largest numnber is = %d", big);
    }
    else
        printf("The largest numnber is not detected");
    return 0;
}
```